# Understanding mean curvature of a 3D surface

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates, mean, surface

I am currently trying to understand the calculation of the mean curvature for a 3D surface, where one coordinate is a function of the other two coordinates.

Looking at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature#Surfaces_in_3D_space under "[For the special case of a surface defined as a function of two coordinates, e.g. z = S(x,y)]" they give this formula:

[mean curvature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OQUy.jpg)

What i don't understand here is the `div(z - S)` . If z = S(x,y) then i would think that z is the same as S and thus `z - S` equals 0.
I tried to follow the cited literature but i didn't find what i was looking for.
Apparently i misunderstand something here and z is not the same as S?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general math tech support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-S(x,y)` is a function of 3 variables, the gradient of which is `(-S_x,-S_y,1)`, see the second line. Then you normalize this gradient vector and compute the divergence of the normalized vector field.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got hung up on the z = S(x,y), but i understand it now and actually go for an implementation.